# I cannot log into Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I cannot log into Google Analytics. I click the "log into Google Analytics" button and nothing happens. It reloads the current page.

So far as I know, I didn't upgrade anything, change anything, or modify my account in any way.

Comment: Try a different browser.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are logged into your Google account that is linked to Google Analytics.

Try accessing the page now. If that does not work try directly going to your Homepage by following this link:
https://www.google.com/analytics/web/#home

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Nope. I can't even sign up! I don't understand why I suddenly can't access this.

Comment: @Francine You didn't say you have a sign up problem you said you had a problem with logging into it.